# Can an item in an ItemsControl be the target of a binding?

Tags: wpf

In the code below I want the second item to be bound to a property on my viewmodel.
How do I accomplish that?  I don't want to create a list or ObservableCollection in code.

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <local:InfoTableItem Data="Hi there!"/>
        <local:InfoTableItem Data="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
    </ItemsControl.Items>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>




public class InfoTableItem : DependencyObject
{

    public string Data
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(string), typeof(InfoTableItem), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));

}
```

Comment: So do you get an error message at runtime or a compiler error?

Comment: Neither, the binding displays nothing.

Comment: Did you watch your ouput window, where the Binding errors appear?

Comment: Thank you, a valuable resource which I forget!! I don't understand this error msg am researching it now: Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Observation.ObsDate; DataItem=null; target element is 'InfoTableItem' (HashCode=28714034); target property is 'Data' (type 'String')

Comment: @Sam Can you close the question if it has been answered.

Comment: The question has not been answered.  I have to work on other things till the end of the day unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a more concise statement of the question asked here:

[How do I write this ItemsControl so WPF will use bindings to generate columns for the output grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994712/how-do-i-write-this-itemscontrol-so-wpf-will-use-bindings-to-generate-columns-fo/31039779#31039779)

See the above for the answer.